# Is there an easy way to specify a wildcard character in a regex for coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I want to be able to say

```
if target.hostname == string.match(/attacker./)
```

and match to any hostname that has a string such as "attacker1", "attacker2", etc.

I can't seem to find the equivalent in coffeescript. Perhaps someone knows this regex syntax?

Update:

I have used the example from here: http://www.elijahmanor.com/regular-expressions-in-coffeescript-are-awesome/

to create this regex:

```
attackerPattern = /// ^ # begin of line
      /attacker/ # the word "attacker"
      ([0-9]+)     # followed by a number
      \.           # followed by a dot
      ([a-zA-Z]+)  # followed by one or more letters
      \.           # followed by a dot
      ([/com/])      # followed by a com
///i # end of line and ignore case
```

because I want to catch something that said "attacker1.node.com" or "attacker2.node.com", etc.

I seem to be able to catch this with the pattern:

```
attackerPattern = /attacker/i
```

and maybe this is enough (because it won't care about the rest of the hostname), but I kind of want it more specific to the example, where it NEEDS to have the .someword.com after "attacker1". Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `/attacker([0-9]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)\.com/` work?

Comment: Nope. However, `/attacker/i` seems to work just fine.